# Dependent Clauses

Tags: subordinate-clauses

Identifying the mistake in the sentence:

**Who are** unknown in most of the northeastern United States, grits are a common Southern dish.

According to the answer key, WHO ARE is the part of the sentence the is wrong.

What do you think is the correct substitute to WHO ARE? (THAT, WHICH, WHAT)

Is it a noun clause, adverbial clause, relative clause?

Thank you so much

Comment: Are (THAT, WHICH, WHAT) the only options you have as substitutes?  None of them make sense to me.  The only words I could put there are things like "While" or "Although".

Comment: I would begin the sentence with _Although they are..._

Comment: You could simply start 'Unknown in..." The sentence makes perfect sense without anything else.

Comment: Context matters, but first thing to my mind would be `While they are` ... Since `grits` is an object rather than a person, `Who` is certainly not appropriate.

Comment: "Although they are unknown in most of the northeastern United States, grits are a common Southern dish."